# Crashing core data application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have setup my first core data project. Everything works fine until I do the following (in Simulator/Device):

• Close App using "Home Button" 
• Double press "Home Button" and quit the app from background.
• Reopen the app

As soon as it reopens there is an instant crash with nothing in the log. The last thing logged is "Program received signal:  “SIGKILL”." which was when I terminate the app.

I have tried adding NSLog(@"")'s into the "main" function also in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" and it never gets there after the relaunch?

I have repeated the same steps in Core Data Books (Apples Sample app) and it does the same - so it's not just me :o) - Although if I set up and "out of the box" - Navigation based application with Core data it DOES NOT crash?

Can anyone else recreate this and is there a simple solution?

Thanks
James

Comment: I was using the Core Data Book code from the XCode Bundle. I downloaded it from the Apple website and this version is fine. I am now comparing the 2 versions? Although this still doesnt fix my application. Please help!

Comment: Also in XCode next to the Console button it says "mach_msg_trap"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only happens if you are using "Build and Debug" if you run through "Build and Run" it's fine!

ANNOYING BUG!!!

James